# How do I run Maltego after installing it?

Tags: 12.04, apt

I installed Maltego from Paterva's website and it successfully installed. Now, how do I run it? I typed "maltego" on the terminal a zillion times and it comes back with "command not found". I tried entering "sudo apt-get install maltego" and get back with "maltego is already the newest version". There is no icon on the desktop or applications menu, but the Ubuntu Software Center reports that it was successfully installed. What do I do??

Edit: I found the icon but it doesn't respond to any command

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information by [edit]ing your question and telling us: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the output to `locate maltego` is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information... (Please help us help you!) Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure it installed properly check to see if `/usr/bin/maltego_community` exists. You should be able to run this file to open Maltego.

You need superuser access for this:
To add the shortcut, make a new file called `maltego-community.desktop`
Open the file with a text editor and paste in the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=4.0
Type=Application
Name=Maltego Community
GenericName=Maltego Classic
Comment=Visualise, Map and Mine Data
Exec=/usr/bin/maltego_community
Icon=maltego_community

Terminal=false

Actions=ConfigureMemory;ShowWebsite;

[Desktop Action ConfigureMemory]
Name=Configure Memory
Exec=/usr/bin/maltego_community_memory_config

[Desktop Action ShowWebsite]
Name=Paterva Website
Exec=x-www-browser https://www.paterva.com
```

If Maltego doesn't run, it may be because you don't have Java installed.
Install it by running `sudo apt install default-jre`